# What is a non-fundamental force?

Tags: forces, terminology, definition, interactions

We all know of the four fundamental forces, gravity, electromagnetism, strong, and weak. However, is there such a thing as a non-fundamental force, and if so, what is the definition of such a thing? Can anyone give examples of non-fundamental forces?

Comment: Friction? Viscous drag? Any elastic force?

Comment: The Higgs-exchange force is a further fundamental force you skipped. There are residual induced strong forces, e.g. by the exchange of pions and other mesons. Any good text will clarify things prodigiously for you.

Comment: Is this mainstream? I thought fundamental forces are usually not read from effective theories and moreover correspond to gauge bosons, could you point to a reference on this please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you should first know the fundamental forces (gravitation, weak, strong and electromagnetism). All other forces are manifestations of these four fundamental forces. Tension, friction,  and air resistance are some examples of non-fundamental forces.

All the fundamental forces appear to be conserative but most of non-fundamental forces are non-conservative.